# Showing that a linear operator is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the linear operator $L_1: l^2\rightarrow l^2$ defined by $L_1\langle x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n, \ldots\rangle = \langle1 x_1, 2x_2, \ldots , nx_n,\ldots\rangle$ is not continuous.

Can this be done using the P-sereis?

Comment: Are you sure that $L_1$(X) is in $l^2$ for all vector X?

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is.

Comment: As @LuisGomezSanchez suggested, this operator does not map $l^2$ into $l^2.$ So this problem can't even get out of the starting gate.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to show it's not bounded.

Consider the sequence $a^{(n)}_k = 1$ if $k=n$, $0$ either

Then $\|a^{(n)}\| = 1$, but $\|L_1(a^{(n)})\| = n \to + \infty$

Comment: Can the p-series be used to solve?

Comment: Not bounded? It's doesn't even map into $l^2.$

Answer (score 0):

If you know that a linear operator is continuous if and only if the boundary of the unit ball is mapped to a bounded set, then you can take the sequence

$$(e_n)_n$$

Where $e_n$ is the sequence with $1$ on $n$th entry and $0$ elsewhere. Then for all $n \in \Bbb N$ $|| e_n ||=1$ but $|| L_1(e_n) ||= n$

Comment: Can the p-series be used to solve?

Comment: Used to solve what?

Comment: It was suggested we solve this question using the p-series, do you know how this would be done?

Comment: @KellySanchez I have a doubt now: I don't know why is this function well defined, for example, $(1/n)_n$ is in $l^2$ but $(n\frac{1}{n})_n=(1)_n$ is not in $l^2$. I think the function should be restricted to those squences that are eventually zero.

Comment: Thats that I thought, but they insisted it could be done, using the p-series

Comment: @KellySanchez I think that the problem asked to prove this function is not defined on all $l^2$, and I've showed you that using precisely the $p-$series. Now, if you restrict to sequences that vanishes eventually, the function is well defined and it's not continuous.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now.

Comment: @KellySanchez Glad it helped. In case you don't know, you can choose an accepted answer (it has not to be mine). Consider choosing an accepted answer for all your other posts.